# Verses similar to Gita 2:42 in the Vedas and Upanishads?

Tags: vedas, upanishads, gita

> [[**BG 2:42**]](https://asitis.com/2/42-43.html) : Men of small knowledge are very much attached to the flowery words of the Vedas, which recommend various fruitive activities for elevation to heavenly planets, resultant good birth, power, and so forth. Being desirous of sense gratification and opulent life, they say that there is nothing more than this.

Since Gita is the summary of Vedas and Upanishads, can we find a similar verse like this in the Vedas and Upanishads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some similar verses from Upanishads are

> The eighteen persons necessary for the **performance of sacrifice are
> transitory** and not permanent and karma in its nature inferior, has
> been stated as resting upon these. Those ignorant persons who delight
> in this, as leading to bliss, **again fall into decay** and
> death. (Mundaka Upanishad 1.2.7)
>
> The ignorant following the diverse ways of ignorance, flatter
> themselves that their objects have been accomplished. As these
> followers of karma do not learn the truth owing to their desire, they
> grow miserable and after the fruits of their karma are consumed, fall
> from Heaven. **These ignorant men regarding sacrificial and charitable
> acts as most important**, do not know any other help to bliss;
> **having enjoyed in the heights of Heaven the abode of pleasures, they enter again into this** or even inferior world. (Mundaka Upanishad
> 1.2.9-10)
>
> Into blinding darkness (ignorance) enter those who worship ignorance
> (rites). I**nto greater darkness**, as it were, than that enter those
> who are devoted to knowledge (**the ceremonial portion of the
> Vedas**). (Brihadaranyaka Upanishad 4.4.10)

Comment: Thanks for the answer